# Unit test fails in conditional rendering in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test the status of my application but I put a condition on it, due to which my unit test fails and delivering an error message the expecting number of calls 0 instead of 1.

tsx file

```
if (success) {
    if (isOnline) {
      await setOffline();
    } else {
      await setOnline();
    }
  }
```

test file

```
it('testing', async () => {

jest
  .spyOn(props, 'setOffline')
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());

await wrapper
  .find('toggleButton')
  .simulate('valueChange')

expect(props.setOffline).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

});

Comment: Please show full code component and test file

Comment: @jaskarn, your code is not enough to help you, please share more code.